# When I run mokutil, I get Failed to enroll new keys

Tags: debian, secure-boot

When I run `mokutil --import MOK.der`, I get

```
❯ mokutil --import MOK.der
input password: 
password should be 1~256 characters
input password: 
Failed to enroll new keys
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was very simply, run it as root

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```